# Configuring minimum priced product on clicking on the base product on PLP

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have variant products and base products configured in my project.

I have a requirement whereby when I click on the base product, I should get the PDP of the variant with least price.

Is it configurable or will I have to override the custom URL resolver for this?

Answer (score 0):

Where do you get your prices? You could write a flexible search logic, that only returns the variant with the lowest price (row). Set this one as full/update query of your SolR indexing job and you should be done.